# Why does binding affect the type of my map?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, language-implementation

I was playing around in the REPL and I got some weird behavior:

```
Clojure 1.4.0
user=> (type {:a 1})
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
user=> (def x {:a 1})
#'user/x
user=> (type x)
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

I thought that all small literal maps were instances of `PersistentArrayMap`, but apparently that's not the case if it's been bound with `def`. Why would using `def` cause Clojure to choose a different representation for my litte map? I know it's probably just some strange implementation detail, but I'm curious.

Comment: Interestingly that only happens when its a literal map, i.e., it doesn't happen when calling `(def x (array-map :a 1))`.

Comment: So if you explicitly say you want an array map then it doesn't change the type. I guess this means it has something to do specifically with how Clojure picks the structure to back a map _literal_.

Comment: What is your Clojure version. I got same for both, `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`.

Comment: @Kugathasan Abimaran - My question has the version info in the repl session I included. What version are you using? I tried it in a 1.3 repl and got the same result.

Comment: @DaoWen : Sorry, I couldn't noticed it. My version is 1.2.1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question made me dig into the Clojure source code. I just spent a few hours putting print statements in the source in order to figure this out.

#### It turns out the two map expressions are evaluated through different code paths

`(type {:a 1})` causes Java byte-code to be emitted and ran. The emitted code use `clojure.lang.RT.map()` to construct the map which returns a **PersistentArrayMap** for small maps:

```
static public IPersistentMap map(Object... init){
    if(init == null)
        return PersistentArrayMap.EMPTY;
    else if(init.length <= PersistentArrayMap.HASHTABLE_THRESHOLD)
        return PersistentArrayMap.createWithCheck(init);
    return PersistentHashMap.createWithCheck(init);
}
```

When evaluating `(def x {:a 1})` at least from the REPL there's no byte-code emitted. The constant map is parsed as a **PersistentHashMap** in `clojure.lang.Compiler$MapExpr.parse()` which returns it warpped it in a `ConstantExpr`:

```
else if(constant)
{
IPersistentMap m = PersistentHashMap.EMPTY;
for(int i=0;i<keyvals.length();i+= 2)
    {
    m = m.assoc(((LiteralExpr)keyvals.nth(i)).val(), ((LiteralExpr)keyvals.nth(i+1)).val());
    }
//System.err.println("Constant: " + m);
return new ConstantExpr(m);
}
```

The `def` expression when evaluated binds the value of the `ConstantExpr` created above which as as said is a **PersistentHashMap**.

#### So why is it implemented this way?

I don't know. It could be simple oversight or the PersistentArrayMap optimization may not really be worth it.

Comment: Very nice explanation! According to you answer, compiling the .clj and running it outside the REPL should result in both values being of type `PersistentArrayMap`. I added a main method to print the two types, uberjar'd it up and ran it with `java -jar` and sure enough they were both array maps!