# Good Clojure representation for unordered pairs?

Tags: clojure, set

I'm creating unordered pairs of data elements.  A comment by @Chouser on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270598/what-is-the-data-structure-behind-clojures-sets) says that hash-sets are implemented with 32 children per node, while sorted-sets are implemented with 2 children per node.  Does this mean that my pairs will take up less space if I implement them with sorted-sets rather than hash-sets (assuming that the data elements are Comparable, i.e. can be sorted)?  (I doubt it matters for me in practice.  I'll only have hundreds of these pairs, and lookup in a two-element data structure, even sequential lookup in a vector or list, should be fast.  But I'm curious.)

Answer (score 1):

When comparing explicitly looking at the first two elements of a list, to using Clojure's built in sets I don't see a significant difference when running it ten million times:

```
user> (defn my-lookup [key pair] 
         (condp = key 
               (first pair) true 
               (second pair) true false))
#'user/my-lookup

user> (time (let [data `(1 2)] 
              (dotimes [x 10000000] (my-lookup (rand-nth [1 2]) data ))))
"Elapsed time: 906.408176 msecs"
nil

user> (time (let [data #{1 2}] 
               (dotimes [x 10000000] (contains? data (rand-nth [1 2])))))
"Elapsed time: 1125.992105 msecs"
nil
```

Of course micro-benchmarks such as this are inherently flawed and difficult to really do well so don't try to use this to show that one is better than the other. I only intend to demonstrate that they are very similar.

Comment: Thanks very much for going through the trouble of setting up the micro-benchmark.  That's about what I would have expected.  I imagine lists take up less space than hash-sets, and that vectors take up even less space.  I got similar results using a vector to represent the set, replacing `(first pair)` with `(pair 0)` and `(second pair)` with `(pair 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm doing something with unordered pairs, I usually like to use a *map* since that makes it easy to look up the *other* element. E.g., if my pair is *[2 7]*, then I'll use `{2 7, 7 2}`, and I can do `({2 7, 7 2} 2)`, which gives me `7`.

As for space, the [`PersistentArrayMap`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentArrayMap.java) implementation is actually very space conscious. If you look at the source code (see previous link), you'll see that it allocates an `Object[]` of the exact size needed to hold all the key/value pairs. I think this is used as the default map type for all maps with no more than 8 key/value pairs.

The only catch here is that you need to be careful about duplicate keys. `{2 2, 2 2}` will cause an exception. You could get around this problem by doing something like this: `(merge {2 2} {2 2})`, i.e. `(merge {a b} {b a})` where it's possible that `a` and `b` have the same value.

Here's a little snippet from my repl:

```
user=> (def a (array-map 1 2 3 4))
#'user/a
user=> (type a)
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
user=> (.count a) ; count simply returns array.length/2 of the internal Object[]
2
```

*Note that I called `array-map` explicitly above. This is related to a question I asked a while ago related to map literals and `def` in the repl: [Why does binding affect the type of my map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991694/why-does-binding-affect-the-type-of-my-map)*

Comment: Very nice suggestion.  The two-way lookup idea is useful, and I shouldn't have to worry about duplicate keys in my application.  And thanks for ref to the wierd behavior of curly braces in the REPL.

Comment: @Mars - If you don't need to be able to look up the other item, then just storing `{a a, b b}` will make it behave just like a set—but since it's backed by an array it'll take up less space. It will actually probably have better performance than the set as well, since it just does a linear search through the 2 keys in the array, meaning it does at most 2 `equal?` operations, and then it knows if the key is in the map or not. (That's the reason the default is an array-map and not a hash-map for map literals with just a few keys.)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but i'm too short in reputation and too eager to share information.
If you are concerned about performance clj-tuple by Zachary Tellman may be 2-3 times faster than ordinary list/vectors, as claimed here [ztellman / clj-tuple](https://github.com/ztellman/clj-tuple).

Comment: No, that deserves to be an answer.  I'm not really worried too much about performance on lookup in a pair, but I will take a look at clj-tuple anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't planning to benchmark different pair representations now, but @ArthurUlfeldt's answer and @DaoWen's led me to do so.  Here are my results using criterium's `bench` macro.  Source code is below.  To summarize, as expected, there are no large differences between the seven representations I tested.  However, there is a gap between times for the fastest, array-map and hash-map, and the others.  This is consistent with DaoWen's and Arthur Ulfeldt's remarks.

Average execution time in seconds, in order from fastest to slowest (MacBook Pro, 2.3GHz Intel Core i7):

array-map: 5.602099

hash-map: 5.787275

vector: 6.605547

sorted-set: 6.657676

hash-set: 6.746504

list: 6.948222

Edit: I added a run of `test-control` below, which does only what is common to all of the different other tests.  `test-control` took, on average, 5.571284 seconds.  It appears that there is a bigger difference between the `-map` representations and the others than I had thought: Access to a hash-map or an array-map of two entries is essentially instantaneous (on my computer, OS, Java, etc.), whereas the other representations take about a second for 10 million iterations.  Which, given that it's 10M iterations, means that those operations are still *almost* instantaneous.  (My guess is that the fact that `test-arraymap` was faster than `test-control` is due to noise from other things happening in the background on the computer.  Or it could have to do with idiosyncrasies of compilation.)

(A caveat: I forgot to mention that I'm getting a warning from criterium: "JVM argument TieredStopAtLevel=1 is active, and may lead to unexpected results as JIT C2 compiler may not be active."  I believe this means that Leiningen is starting Java with a command line option that is geared toward the -server JIT compiler, but is being run instead with the default -client JIT compiler.  So the warning is saying "you think you're running -server, but you're not, so don't expect -server behavior."  Running with -server might change the times given above.)

```
(use 'criterium.core)

;; based on Arthur Ulfedt's answer:
(defn pairlist-contains? [key pair] 
  (condp = key 
    (first pair) true 
    (second pair) true 
    false))

(defn pairvec-contains? [key pair] 
  (condp = key 
    (pair 0) true 
    (pair 1) true
    false))

(def ntimes 10000000)

;; Test how long it takes to do what's common to all of the other tests
(defn test-control []
    (print "=============================\ntest-control:\n")
    (bench
      (dotimes [_ ntimes]
        (def _ (rand-nth [:a :b])))))

(defn test-list []
  (let [data '(:a :b)] 
    (print "=============================\ntest-list:\n")
    (bench
      (dotimes [_ ntimes]
        (def _ (pairlist-contains? (rand-nth [:a :b]) data))))))

(defn test-vec []
  (let [data [:a :b]] 
    (print "=============================\ntest-vec:\n")
    (bench
      (dotimes [_ ntimes]
        (def _ (pairvec-contains? (rand-nth [:a :b]) data))))))

(defn test-hashset []
  (let [data (hash-set :a :b)]
    (print "=============================\ntest-hashset:\n")
    (bench
      (dotimes [_ ntimes]
        (def _ (contains? data (rand-nth [:a :b])))))))

(defn test-sortedset []
  (let [data (sorted-set :a :b)]
    (print "=============================\ntest-sortedset:\n")
    (bench
      (dotimes [_ ntimes]
        (def _ (contains? data (rand-nth [:a :b])))))))

(defn test-hashmap []
  (let [data (hash-map :a :a :b :b)]
    (print "=============================\ntest-hashmap:\n")
    (bench
      (dotimes [_ ntimes]
        (def _ (contains? data (rand-nth [:a :b])))))))

(defn test-arraymap []
  (let [data (array-map :a :a :b :b)]
    (print "=============================\ntest-arraymap:\n")
    (bench
      (dotimes [_ ntimes]
        (def _ (contains? data (rand-nth [:a :b])))))))

(defn test-all []
  (test-control)
  (test-list)
  (test-vec)
  (test-hashset)
  (test-sortedset)
  (test-hashmap)
  (test-arraymap))
```